# write to text file in C# from rich textbox including new lines

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to write text to a text file.  I have googled a lot and tried a lot.  I can get it to write to a file, that's not a problem.  However it does not include the new line character apparently.  I have a Windows form.  It has a single rich textbox on it.  The user types in whatever they want, and I pass that text to the variable "plainText".  I want to then save whatever is in that variable to a text file.  Here is what I currently have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Keep_it_Private
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    string plainText = null;
    string path = @"C:\Users\Brannon\Desktop\temp.txt";

       public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plainText = richTextBox1.Text;
        File.WriteAllText(path, plainText);
    }
  }
}
```

I am currently using Visual Studios 2012 and Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to use the string[] textBox.Lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RichTextBox.SaveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1(v=vs.100).aspx) Method.

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

[`RichTextBoxStreamType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextboxstreamtype(v=vs.100).aspx) specifies the types of input and output streams used to load and save data in the `RichTextBox` control.